# Nuxt generate failing with self is not defined in a vue dist file

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, static-site-generation, nuxtjs2

I'm preparing to deploy my first Static app from a Nuxt.js 2 project.

While the static routes are generated fine, my dynamic routes are not. Once I remembered they were hidden in my dropdown menu - duhh - I created a /generate page which renders all my dynamic routes using the nuxt-link component. My assumption was that the crawler should find the /generate/index.vue page and thus the links on it, and crawl those.

It didn't.

Then I noticed a comment from Sebastien Chopin mentioning that SSR should be enabled when generating Static apps. Ok. So I re-enabled SSR and I've hit nothing but errors. A couple I've figured out but this latest one has got me stumped.

[image: Self is not defined in vue dist file]

Some googling has not revealed a clue that appeared relevant - or at least I didn't recognise them as relevant - so I need the 'worldwide developers' team help.

Does this error suggest there's an issue in Vue itself? I don't use 'self' anywhere in my app code soooo... hmmm?

Cheers,
Jeremy

Comment: Sharing some code may be helpful here, hard to say what is the issue without a Github repo or [repro].

Comment: You are right @kissu, as it's a private repo I'll have to create a reproducible example which I haven't found the time for yet. Deployment prep is pending soon so I'll create reproduce example to accompany this post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's generating now (has been for a few weeks, been a busy time!)... however the generated pages are not outputting with content, but I think that's a different issue.

My configuration currently is;

```
target: 'static',
ssr: false,
generate: {
    minify: false, // Nuxt 2.15.4 > Deprecated next major version > Use build.html.minify instead!
    routes: dynamicRoutes
}
```

I'll keep working on it.